# ValueError: too many values to unpack (odoo)

Tags: python, odoo

i want to extract estimated cost from order line when the product name is ups standard or saver,
i get always this error : ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
ValueError: Expected singleton: sale.order.line(118, 119, 120, 121)

what shall i do? Any help please

```
@api.depends('product_id.name')
def _compute_estimated_cost(self):
        estim_cost = 0
        #
        for order_line in self:
            if order_line.product_id.name in ['UPS Standard' ,'UPS Saver']:
                for word in order_line.product_id.name.split():
                    try: 
                        estim_cost += round(float(word),2)
                        self.estim_cost=estim_cost
                       
                        break
                    except:
                        continue
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace (and format it as code), please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
self.estim_cost=estim_cost
```

to

```
order_line.estim_cost=estim_cost
```

Comment: @md1999 Why do you convert product name (type of string of charaters) to float? In your case, **word** in your inner **for loop** will only be **UPS, Standard or Saver**

Comment: Hi, because i want to extract estimated cost generated from ups standard or saver in model sale order line

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong in this line :

```
self.estim_cost=estim_cost
```

You should use order_line instead of self.
Here self is **multiton** sale.order.line(118, 119, 120, 121) and you can not use affectation operator in that situation. 
PS : If you want to write a value in recordsets, use the method .write()

Comment: it doesn't work, is till get the error too many value expected and ValueError: Expected singleton: sale.order.line(132, 133, 134)...